# how to run Python script from php

Tags: php, python, linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I want to run python script from php.
this is my python code. It is saved in /home/pi and name of file is hello.py

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import bluetooth

bd_addr="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
port=1
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((bd_addr.port))
data=""
while 1:
  try:
    data +=sock.recv(1024)
    data_end=data.find('\n')
    if data_end!=-1:
      rec=data[:data_end]
      print datas
      data=data[data_end+1:]
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      break
```

And here is my php code. It is saved in /var/www/html and name of file is php.php

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('ls -l /home/pi/hello.py');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

And I insert localhost/php.php in chrome, it displays

```
-rw-r-r- 1 pi pi 378 Mar 8 12:07 /home/pi/hello.py
```

what is the problem??

Comment: Seriously? It's working correctly, you're running a `ls` (_list_) command, not python. Want to run it as python? Call the python binary.

Comment: How can I call the python binary??

Answer (score 1):

`ls` command is used to list files in a directory or to get information about a file. You are `ls`-ing on your python file and the result is correct. It is providing you with information about the file.

Just put the file name inside of `shell_exec` that is `/home/pi/hello.py`. If you do not want to depend on the shebang and the command `python` is available in your shell environment then you can use `python /home/pi/hello.py` instead of bare `/home/pi/hello.py`.

Again, you used the variable `datas` with `print` where you intended to use `data` - fix it.

---

> php code:

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('python /home/pi/hello.py');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

> or:

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('/home/pi/hello.py');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

> python code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import bluetooth

bd_addr="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
port=1
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((bd_addr.port))
data=""
while 1:
  try:
    data +=sock.recv(1024)
    data_end=data.find('\n')
    if data_end!=-1:
      rec=data[:data_end]
      print data
      data=data[data_end+1:]
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      break
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Jon Stirling, you are using "ls" to only listing the content of the folder or to check whether the file exist in that folder. To run the Python code, you need to change the PHP file into something like this:

```
<?PHP
$output=shell_exec('./hello.py');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: thanks for answer sir. I follow your answer but web server displays 403-Forbidden what's wrong to me?

Comment: probably you have permission problem. You need to set chmod a+x filename.php

Comment: Is it permission problem? I made new php file <?php echo"HI";?> and in web browser Hi is displayed, but output of python script is not displayed.

Comment: Try to run the python code using "./hello.py" on the server using ssh. If it works, then it should also work in PHP. If it does not work, try to use "python hello.py"

Comment: Would there be major robustness or scalability issues, in pursuing this practice for stuff that python can do but not PHP?