# How to run python script using php file

Tags: php, python-3.x, localhost

I am trying to run a `python3` script using a `php` file. I have used php functions like `system()`, `shell_exec()`, `exec()` to run that `python3` script but not getting any output on the browser localhost.
I am asking input from the user in a form in php and by using that input as command line argument I am calling a `python3` script using the above-mentioned php functions.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When posting a question about your code, it's important that you include what you've tried. We gladly help you fix your existing code, but we won't write it all for you.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code of PHP you use. Have you enable the errors display of PHP ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run Python script from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189730/how-to-run-python-script-from-php)

Comment: My code is working when I separately run the python3 file but my input  in is php variable and I want to pass that variable to the python3 file