# How to Run a Python File from HTML by Using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a button on my webpage that executes a python script and am trying to create another one that executes javascript and then the python
script.

However, I can't get it to do both. It will either send out the email or change the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var alertTimerId = 0;

function alertTimerClickHandler ( )
{
  if ( document.getElementById("alertTimerButton").value == "RESTART" )
  {
    // Start the timer
    document.getElementById("alertTimerButton").value = "RESTARTING PLEASE WAIT......";
    alertTimerId = setTimeout ( "showAlert()", 3000 );
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("alertTimerButton").value = "RESTART";
    clearTimeout ( alertTimerId );
  }
}

function showAlert ( )
{
  alert ( "process has been restarted" );
  document.getElementById("alertTimerButton").value = "RESTART";
}

</script>
<!-- <form name="update" method="post" >
<button onclick="alertTimerClickHandler()" name = "clickMe" value= "RESTART" id="alertTimerButton" > RESTART </button>
</form> -->
<form action=index.php method= "get">
<input type="button" name="clickMe" id="alertTimerButton" value= "RESTART" onclick="alertTimerClickHandler()" />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['clickMe']))
{
        exec("/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/restartemail.py \"$input_val\""); 
} else{

}
?>
```

my code that works is

```
<form name="update" method="post" >
<button name = "update" type="submit"> Send Update Email </button>
```

```
if (isset($_POST['update']))
    {
            exec("/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/sendemail.py \"$input_val\""); 
    }
```

Comment: Whre does `$input_val` come from?

Comment: Also, the PHP-code will never be executed since you don't actually submit the form at any point. You might want to look into Ajax, if you want the PHP-script to run without the page reloads (like on an ordinary form submit)

Comment: i have added the code that works to the end of the question is there any way to transfer that to the above code

Comment: `$input_val` is vulnerable to command injection

Comment: The reason it works with `<button>` is that it defaults to `type="submit"` which submits the form. If you would change `<input type="button"` to `<input type="submit"`, it should work the same. I don't see the point of changing it from `<button>` to `<input>` though.

Comment: it's working now thankyou, the only issue is the alert isnt popping up

Comment: That's because the page will reload when you submit the form. This is why I mentioned Ajax. With Ajax, you can make a request in the background, without leaving/reloading the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run Python script from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189730/how-to-run-python-script-from-php)