# Run Python from PHP, status 0, not working

Tags: python, php

I'm running simple code in PHP to execute Python code, i write in 2 file: python n php.

PHP code : (exec.php)

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd("/opt/lampp/htdocs/latihan/php_python/pi.py");
$output = exec($command, $out, $status);
print_r($output);
#print_r($out[0]);
echo "</br>";
print_r($status);
echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

$command = shell_exec($command);
echo "<pre>".$command."</pre>";
echo "\n";

ob_start();
passthru('python /opt/lampp/htdocs/latihan/php_python/pi.py');
$output = ob_get_clean(); 

if( ini_get('safe_mode') ){
   echo "safe mode is on";
}
else{
   echo "it's not";
}
?>
```

Python Code : (pi.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("Hello !");
```

Result 1 : (execute in terminal ):

```
Hello !</br>0</br></br><pre>Hello !
</pre>
it's not
```

Result 2 : (execute in browser ):

```
127

it's not
```

My reference :

- [Can I run a Python script as a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423345/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service)
- [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)
- [how to run Python script from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189730/how-to-run-python-script-from-php)
- And other links..

My file permission :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 488 Nov 26 11:13 exec.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data  41 Nov 26 10:18 pi.py
```

My question is, why i can't show result from python in browser ?

It get status 0, is it cause ? i Change permission to `www-data root` for pi.py still got same result(and change other option for both www-data and root or just one of them).

i try run "ls -l" it success shown in browser tough,,

Comment: I am not sure, but who tell you that 0 is failed status?

Comment: The result should be saved to `$out` variable as far as i know

Comment: no, it just question, cz i didn't understand,, maybe it's cause,, some in reference say it cz permission,, `$out` show array in terminal(only array 0, with correct result), but in browser still empty,,

Comment: I've just runned your code. And it worked for me inside docker image with installed python. Here is what I used - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5ec3af129009d137171eadc32cab7985910b3386

Comment: I get `127` when I provide wrong link to python script. I guess your path is wrong

Comment: Did you tried to run in terminal with absolute path? `python /opt/lampp/htdocs/latihan/php_python/pi.py`?

Comment: yes, i did, but if wrong link, why in terminal it's running well..

Comment: I mean try to run in terminal your python script with absolute path to make sure that your url is correct

Comment: i didn't understand.. in my question, both i running with absolut path, and run in terminal and browser, and.. is i missing something,,